# Is there an adapter that will allow me to plug my power source directly into my battery?

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life

I know there are ["external battery chargers for laptops"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0034M0BDC), but I would like to know if there is an adapter that will plug my existing power source directly into my battery.

Does such a thing exist and what is it called?

Comment: Questions asking for product or shopping recommendations are off topic on SU. Please try to restate your questions in terms of a problem and ask for solutions; if they happen to be products (of any price), so be it. You can flag your question for moderator attention once you've done so.

Comment: Ok.  Since the DC jack isn't attached directly to the motherboard anyway http://www.amazon.com/TOSHIBA-SATELLITE-L305-S5955-POWER-CABLE/dp/B005IEEDBU you wouldn't have to be soldering anything.  Second, since the issue is with the broken plastic housing that holds the DC jack in place, Epoxy could solve your issue.  Third, you wouldn't have to do a *complete* dis-assembly to get to the point where you could Epoxy the DC jack into place.  Fourth... did you even get an estimate from a local repair shop on the repair cost for this?

Comment: Oh... and lastly... and most importantly... $83 for something to charge your battery is less than a new laptop... which is what you are looking at if you don't fix this or get the charger.  Why do you think there should be a **cheaper** solution, when you are faced with spending $400+ on replacing the unit if you don't find a solution?

Comment: @bonGart Your criticisms are a bit harsh.  I've already stated I don't want to open the laptop and I'm looking for a specific alternative to buying an external charger.  I'm certainly not comparing it against the cost of a new laptop!  I _know_ that would be much more expensive.  Sheesh! :P

Comment: I work part time for a computer shop and we do this sort of repair quite often, even in my little town. I think you should go that route.

Comment: You are looking for a **cheaper** alternative to the one you already found... not a specific one, since you already found it.  Why do you think it is not worth $83 to get your laptop back in a usable state?  Why do you think it is not worth the time to get an estimate on repairing the laptop?  Why do you not see the value in the skill a repair person would have, in that they could do what you are not willing to do?

Comment: Per the first comment, the question has been restated; suggestions referring to a repair shop are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no.  There is no adapter that will allow you to plug a power source directly into the battery.

You are faced with fixing the laptop.

I was able to fix it myself after finding a guide online.